# Create Jagged edges for a box with CSS

Tags: css, border

Can someone help by explaining how I can achieve this jagged edge on a box with CSS? [Click here for the mockup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mv3e4.png). I'm able to create layered text boxes but not a continuous looking box with the stroke jagged. Thanks!

my code is here:

https://codepen.io/aldina/pen/Qvaegb

```
  .bgtextcolor {
    position: relative;
    background-color: purple;
  }

  .trPic{ 
    position:relative;
    width:320px; 
    height:240px; 
    background: #ffffff; 
    border: 2px solid #000000; 
    padding-left: 5px;
    top: 50px;
   }       
  .pbox{
    padding-left: 5px;

  }      
  .trPic .redO{ 
    position:relative; 
    top: -10px; 
    width: 325px; 
    height: 240px; 
    background:#ffffff; 
    opacity:0;
   border: 2px solid #000000;
  }       
  .trPic
  .redO { opacity:1; } 
</style>
```

```
<div class="trPic"> 
  <div class="redO">
       <div class="pbox">
    <p> this is the text sdjfl sdfklj sdfklj sdfjlsdfjlsd lkjsdlfjsd lkjsdflkjsdf sdklfj sdfj lsdfkl sf lksjdf lkjsdf
    sdfsd
    </p>
     </div>
    </div>
  </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: No worries @Paulie_D, I'm not asking for a code writing service, just advice. I have attempted it but not successfully. Here is what I have if you'd like to review and give pointers and how I could achieve this:  https://codepen.io/aldina/pen/Qvaegb

Answer (score 0):

It may be simpler to use the :before and :after pseudo classes on your box div, and create a background image/sprite with your stagger effect.  Something along these lines:

```
.pbox {
  border-left: 2px solid #333;
  border-right: 2px solid #333;
  max-width:300px;
}

.pbox:before {
  content: " ";
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}

.pbox:after {
  content: " ";
  height: 20px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% + 4px);
  position: relative;
  left: -2px;
}
```

Codepen: https://codepen.io/mediacrisis/pen/eWVNOy

Just replace the red background color with your staggered pixel background image.

Comment: Thank you so much for the tip to use an image in between! I assume there is no way to do it with CSS, correct?

Comment: You could add a bunch of 'step' layers inside a container and try to get the same effect with borders, but its a bit choppy and requires a lot of extra html.  Example: https://codepen.io/mediacrisis/pen/KmQdBL

Comment: I'm going to try the img option as it seems a bit less complicated like you said. Thank you so much for your advice! I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question!